# Displaying time and date on html file using python

Tags: python, html, apache, time

I am trying to use import time, and strftime(), to import time, then use the index.open() to write the date on a html file, this is not working , is there any way to display time on html for every 10 mins for example ?

Comment: Can you show us what is "not working"

Comment: like I type in index.open('time.strftime(%c)'),,